# ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, iisnode

I have a VUE 2 application which doesn't run with iisnode and iis. The stderr log of iisnode says: ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined

node version: 6.9.5
npm version: 4.3.0

This topic is mentioned often here, but the solution didn't work for me. My vendor.js loads before the app.js, but I get this error.

Here are my config files for webpack:

bundle.js:

```
require('./check-versions')()

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

var ora = require('ora')
var rm = require('rimraf')
var path = require('path')
var chalk = require('chalk')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf')

var spinner = ora('building for production...')
spinner.start()

rm(path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, config.build.assetsSubDirectory), err => {
  if (err) throw err
  webpack(webpackConfig, function (err, stats) {
    spinner.stop()
    if (err) throw err
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      modules: false,
      children: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }) + '\n\n')

    console.log(chalk.cyan('  Build complete.\n'))
    console.log(chalk.yellow(
      '  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.\n' +
      '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
    ))
  })
})
```

webpack.base.conf.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  externals: {
    'jquery': 'jQuery'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    modules: [
      resolve('src'),
      resolve('node_modules')
    ],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
      'src': resolve('src'),
      'assets': resolve('src/assets'),
      'components': resolve('src/components')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: "pre",
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

webpack.prod.conf.js:

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
  ? require('../config/test.env')
  : config.build.env

var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin(),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    //new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    //  name: 'manifest',
    //  chunks: ['vendor']
    //}),
    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  var CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

config.js:

```
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../wwwroot/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../wwwroot/'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  },
  dev: {
    env: require('./dev.env'),
    port: 80,
    autoOpenBrowser: true,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '',
    proxyTable: {},
    // CSS Sourcemaps off by default because relative paths are "buggy"
    // with this option, according to the CSS-Loader README
    // (https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#sourcemaps)
    // In our experience, they generally work as expected,
    // just be aware of this issue when enabling this option.
    cssSourceMap: false
  }
}
```

.bablerc:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "stage-0" ],
  "plugins": [ "transform-runtime" ],
  "comments": false,
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [ "istanbul" ]
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "coreui-vue",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.4",
  "description": "Open Source Admin Template",
  "author": "Łukasz Holeczek <lukasz@holeczek.pl>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "unit": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit/specs test/e2e/specs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "auth0-js": "^8.8.0",
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "mini-toastr": "^0.6.5",
    "strip-ansi": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "vue": "2.2.4",
    "vue-chartjs": "2.5.4",
    "vue-notifications": "^0.8.0",
    "vue-router": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-strap": "github:wffranco/vue-strap",
    "vue-video-player": "^3.0.8",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.7",
    "babel-core": "6.24.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "3.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "6.24.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "chromedriver": "2.28.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "3.2.4",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.26.4",
    "eslint": "3.18.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^2.0.7",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "2.1.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "4.15.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.6.1",
    "function-bind": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.4",
    "inject-loader": "2.0.1",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.2.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "lolex": "^1.5.2",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "nightwatch": "0.9.13",
    "opn": "^4.0.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "ora": "^1.1.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "4.1.1",
    "selenium-server": "3.3.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "sinon": "1.17.7",
    "sinon-chai": "2.9.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "vue-style-loader": "2.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.2.4",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.16.1",
    "webpack-merge": "2.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {

  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  }
}
```

I moved the devDependencies also to the dependencies to be sure, that's not the problem.

My generated index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8><title>CoreUI - Open Source Bootstrap Admin Template</title><link href=static/css/font-awesome.min.css rel=stylesheet><link href=static/css/simple-line-icons.css rel=stylesheet><link href=static/css/style.css rel=stylesheet><link href=static/css/app.06e44e579e587787413ab48c2c604c4d.css rel=stylesheet></head><body class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed aside-menu-hidden"><div id=app></div><script type=text/javascript src=static/js/vendor.2cb2e5935748c34893e8.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=static/js/app.9dc82c9f50710d9ababd.js></script></body></html>
```

I hope somebody can help.
Thank you!

Dominik

Comment: All lines after that are uncommented. I don't know exactly what you mean, maybe you can explain it in detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Uncommnet the code you have bellow:

```
// extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
// prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
 name: 'manifest',
 chunks: ['vendor']
}),
```

> **Update;** RemovedPluginError: `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` has been removed, please use `config.optimization.splitChunks` instead.

So basically comment out what you have now and uncomment this one :). This will basically pull out webpack into it's own file and insert it before vendor file and will make sure you have those missing functions injected in the window.

This stuff is done because webpack version will almost never change during your development while other plugins/libraries/plugins might change and you can separate webpack from other libs so it's not uselessly downloaded by users each time you add a new component or change some version and deploy.

Comment: Ok I have done that, now I get another ReferenceError: self is not defined :D

Maybe better than before, but not really good :)

Comment: I changed the webpack version to 3.4.1 but also no success, same error.

Comment: any other info on that? self is not defined is pretty generic. Do you have a stacktrace maybe ?
Oh damn, check the vue-cli template https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/template/build/webpack.prod.conf.js#L71
You need to define the commonschunk plugin twice. So basically have both

Comment: I have tried this already. Sadly there ist the webpackjsonp error back.

Here is the complete stderr file:
`Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ORF.SpotUploadPrototype_Backend\static\js\app.9dc82c9f50710d9ababd.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)`

Comment: `at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js:210:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)`

Comment: Is it possible to disable this bundle functionality, and copy the files as they are? I have to make an deployment, I'm one week too late...